# What is the most suitable coding convention for pointer types?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, naming-conventions

There are two ways to "look at" variable `int * a`:

- You can consider `a` as a variable of type `int*`.
- You can consider `*a` as a variable of type `int`.

Hence, some people would declare `int* a`, whereas others would declare `int *a`.

---

I would like to know with regards to the two approaches above:

- What are the arguments in favor and against each one of them?
- Which one of them is generally consider a better coding convention?

---

The standard appears to be "discouraging" the use of the `int* a` approach:

- It cannot be applied when declaring a function pointer `int (*func)(int x)`.
- It cannot be applied when declaring several pointers in the same line `int *a,*b,*c`.

---

I've been using the `int* a` approach most of my professional life.

But it turns out to be in contrast with what most people do.

Any additional insights will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've been using `int* a` for years, that is what my company's coding standard says too. Just for some anecdotal reinforcement.

Comment: Regardless of whitespace, the declaration will be parsed as `int (*a)`; the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.